# Run Multiple Windows System Commands Interactively From Within R

Tags: r, windows, session, command-line

I am trying to build an R package for Windows 10 that will allow me to use the  Secure File Transfer Protocol (SFTP) client of PuTTY, [PSFTP](https://www.puttygen.com/psftp#targetText=PSFTP%20is%20the%20Secure%20File,between%20computers%20using%20SSH%20connection) from within the R console to transfer files back and forth to an SFTP server (yes, I realize there are other packages out there that can do do SFTP transfers, but I really want to develop this to work specifically with PSFTP).  I think I can get this working if I can simply overcome one obstacle that I don't know how to implement in R.  Is there a way I can call the windows system command and start it as a session of sorts so I can continue to work with it interactively from within R?  I essentially just want to take commands from the R console and pass them into the same windows command line window having one command execute following the previous commands.

A simple toy example will help me explain what I'm trying to do.  Let's say I have to execute multiple Windows system commands in R, line-by-line, like using `cd ..` to change the directory back one level and then list the contents with `dir`.  I could try this:

```
system("cmd.exe", input="cd ..")
system("cmd.exe", input="dir")
```

Obviously this won't work the way I want it to because the there is no "memory" of the first line of code having been executed on the windows system, when I execute the second line.  What I'd like is to have some way, within R to create code like that above so that it would be equivalent to my running a command prompt from a single cmd window and typing the following commands one by one:

```
cd ..
dir
```

In the end, I want to be able to create a Windows Session of sorts—sort of like the way the `rvest` package works.  In `rvest`, users can create a session and then then sequentially send commands to the session and each subsequent command picks up where the last command left off in the session:

```
library(rvest)
session <- html_session("http://hadley.nz")
jump_to(session, "hadley-wickham.jpg")  #this continues with the session via first argument
```

I basically want to implement the same concept as this, where my subsequent lines continue from the previous ones.  Is this possible?  How would I go about doing this with the "cd ..", "dir" example above?  If I can figure that out, I think I'm off to the races.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the subprocess package like this.

```
library(subprocess)

handle <- spawn_process("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe")
Sys.sleep(1)

process_read(handle, PIPE_STDOUT, timeout = 1000)
process_read(handle, PIPE_STDERR)

process_write(handle, "cd ..\n")
process_write(handle, "dir\n")

process_read(handle, PIPE_STDOUT, timeout = 1000)
process_read(handle, PIPE_STDERR)

process_write(handle, 'exit\n')
```

### Other packages

You can also look at the ps package and the processx package (which uses ps).

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you so much.  I'm going to leave this open to see if anyone has other answers, but it looks like this will probably do the trick.  Many thanks!

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I'll accept this as an answer I don't receive any better answers within a day or two.